# Can't find method AddClaims on extension class OpenIddictExtensions

Tags: openiddict

I have installed package OpenIddict.AspNetCore, OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore, OpenIddict.Quartz Version 3.1.1 but I'm missing method AddClaims and SetDestinations.
I found ArgumentNullException:
No overload for method 'AddClaims' takes 2 arguments
Please, help me fixing this. Thanks.

Comment: Got the same while trying Balosar from openIddict samples. [identity.AddClaims(Claims.Role, (await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)).ToImmutableArray());]
Why don't you try something easier with full example as in this link. https://dev.to/robinvanderknaap/setting-up-an-authorization-server-with-openiddict-part-i-introduction-4jid

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the 4.0.0-preview2 packages. The extension method is part of the `OpenIddictExtensions` class in `OpenIddict.Abstractions` namespace. However, pre-release versions are generally not stable and the API might change before the actual 4.0 release.

[Namespace and Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uog2s.png)

[The function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CH93.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the message, I assume you have code that looks like

```
something.AddClaims(arg1, arg2);
```

The compiler is telling you that there is an `AddClaims` method but it should be called with more than two arguments or with one or none, e.g.

```
something.AddClaims();
something.AddClaims(arg);
something.AddClaims(arg1, arg2, arg3); // and so on
```